# Polyfill type definitions not getting picked up

Tags: typescript, typescript-definitions

I'm using TypeScript 4.4.4 and I'm trying to use this EventSource polyfill in my frontend (React): https://github.com/EventSource/eventsource. I've also installed the type definitions for that package.

I specifically need to add headers to the SSE initiation: `eventSourceRef.current = new EventSource('/api/foo', { headers: { bar: 'buzz' } });`. Unfortunately, the type definitions aren't being picked up. TypeScript complains if I try to add `headers` as a property to the `EventSourceInit` options, which means that the types of the baked in `EventSource` are still being used, not the polyfill definitions.

I suspect it might have something to do with that the polyfill package doesn't export the class itself, so I can't import the class. I have to import the whole package, like this: `import 'eventsource/lib/eventsource-polyfill';`

I've tried the following:

- import the polyfill in my entry file
- import the polyfill only in the file that I need it
- import the type definition reference: `/// <reference path='../../../../../node_modules/@types/eventsource/index.d.ts'/>`
- extend the global type and try to extend the `EventSourceInit` interface with the new properties allowed by the polyfill, like so:

```
export {};
declare global {
    interface EventSourceInit {
        headers?: object | undefined;
    }
}
```

I realize I could always just cast it as any or import using require, but I feel like if there are type definitions for this it should be possible to use them in my project.

What am I missing here?

Edit:
I also tried the following, but none worked either:

- import the package as shown in the type definition tests: `import EventSourcePolyfill = require("eventsource/lib/eventsource-polyfill");`. This doesn't work because I'm targeting ECMAScript modules.
- import it like this: `import EventSourcePolyfill from "eventsource/lib/eventsource-polyfill";`. However, when calling the constructor (`const foo = new EventSourcePolyfill('/foo)`) TypeScript complains that the expression is not constructable, as "Type 'typeof EventSource' has no construct signatures".

Answer (score 0):

Sigh... I found the way. I started typing out the `EventEmitter` class in an expression and I noticed the intellisense suggesting the class coming from the package. This is the way to import it, apparently:

`import EventSource from 'eventsource';`

I had been trying to import 'eventsource/lib/eventsource-polyfill' as per the instructions in the package README:

> Just add example/eventsource-polyfill.js file to your web page:

> `<script src=/eventsource-polyfill.js></script>`

I got confused by that and tried importing the wrong thing. But apparently just importing the package index suffices. I guess the simplest answer really is the best.